# Reem_sim/ ROS Hydro on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My env: Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), ROS kinetic.

I need to work with **Reem robot simulation**. I tried following instructions as per [Launching a REEM Gazebo simulation](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/REEM/Tutorials/Launching%20a%20REEM%20Gazebo%20simulation). But got stuck at

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

which returned

```
ERROR the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies
reem_tabletop_grasping: No definition of [object_recognition_msgs] for OS version [xenial]
reem_moveit_config No definition of [moveit_simple_controller_manager] for OS version [xenial]
```

So how do I get this running. Should I install Ros Hydro? But ROS Hydro ONLY supports Precise, Quantal, and Raring for debian packages, as per [Ubuntu install of ROS Hydro](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu).

Should I install Ubuntu Raring for this now? Thank You

---

Edit: tried `$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y`

It says,

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
reem_tabletop_grasping: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_commander]
reem_bringup: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [play_motion]
reem_object_recognition: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [object_recognition_tabletop]
reem_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245549/reem_sim/-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-12**:
Please check your question after / before posting it. I've had to significantly edit it, as it was completely unreadable before. Using proper formatting will make it easier for other users to help you, which in turn increases your chances of getting good answers.

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-12**:
Thank u @gvdhoorm. Sorry for the noobie formatting (I really am a noobie). I didn't understand how to get the 'code' block and a blank line.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-14**:
Your latest edit seems to suggest this is a new problem (you're not running 16.04 anymore). I would suggest you open a new question for that to keep things clear for future readers.

Apart from that: do you have `ros-hydro-imu-sensor-controller` installed? The REEM pkgs may not declare that dep.

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-14**:
I was hoping REEM pkgs to handle that. Thanks a lot for the tip.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-14**:
The reem pkgs should have that dependency declared, yes, but if they don't, then a `rosdep install ..` won't pick them up. Perhaps report the issue over at their bug tracker.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-14**:
Also: I just noticed that there is an Indigo version of all of this. That would probably have had a better chance to work on Kinetic than the Hydro version ..

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-14**:
I too found indigo version for **REEM C** robot. Is that gonna work with REEM?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-14**:
Probably not. REEM is a different robot from REEM C. I was actually referring to [reemc-sim-indigo.rosinstall](https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal-ros-pkg/blob/master/reemc-sim-indigo.rosinstall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried it, but you could see whether leaving off the `--rosdistro hydro` from the `rosdep install ..` command makes this work.

No guarantees, as the main [wiki/Robots/REEM](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/REEM) explicitly mentions Hydro as being the target platform.

---

Edit: MoveIt hasn't been released on Kinetic, so `rosdep` cannot resolve those two packages. You can see whether things will work if you build it [from source](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-13**:
Tried that, didn't work. Created a bootable USB with 13.04 and met with "Kernel Panic". Looks like a bad day. Getting 12.04 now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
"Didn't work" is not really informative. What happened?

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-13**:
Thank You for that edit. [It](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/) seems to be in Beta. I'm skeptical.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
(moveit maintainer here): we have multiple ppl building moveit from source on Kinetic and using it daily. There are some rough edges, but the install instructions should work. If they don't, please report to the moveit issue tracker on github.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
Btw: I'd recommend using a workspace underlay for MoveIt. Then overlay your reem workspace on top of that.

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-13**:
Could you pls point me to some sort of a guide/tutorial.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
For building MoveIt? See the 'from source' link I posted above.

For overlaying workspaces? See [Overlaying with catkin workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying).